# How to get multiple map[string]int through channel and union of them into one map?

Tags: go, maps, goroutine, channel

I am implementing a function that counts words and I am trying to write this with goroutines. So far I have made `[]string` arrays to suitable sizes of the original string text and I send these to a goroutine each to count the words and add them to k/v pair inside a `map[string]int`, then I want to take them all through my channel and read all of the maps and simply count how many words in total there has been and return this `map[string]int`, but this is where I am lost. I tried to do something like

```
mapSummary := make(map[string]int)
for k, v := range channel {
    mapSummary[k] += v
}
```

but this does not work since I am using two variables in the range, and with only one I am not sure how to do this. So how do I add all of these maps together that I sent through a channel? I dont need you guys to show me exactly how this is done (it is a homework assignment) but since I did not recieve any help from my TAs in our labsession I would greatly appreciate some clues as to how this should be done, I also see that how I distribute the `[]string` array is not good, but that I will figure out myself! :) This code does not include the main function or a majority of the code, but the necessary parts that I hope help you understand it.

```
ch := make(chan map[string]int)
for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    words := text[i*(len(text)/8):(i+1)*(len(text)/8)]
    go count(words, ch, wg)
}
wg.Wait()

mapSummary := make(map[string]int)
for k, v := range ch {
    mapSummary[k] += v
}
return mapSummary

func count(words []string, ch chan<- map[string]int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    freqs := make(map[string]int)
    for _, word := range words {
        freqs[word] += 1
    }
    wg.Done()
    ch <- freqs
}
```

it tells me "too many variables in range".

Comment: If I use for k, v := range channel it tells me to many variables in range, so I dont know how to do it then. So my problem is, how do I iterate over all of my maps that I send through the channel and get the union of them into one map? I understand that I need to add all the keys to the unionMap and then sum all the integers from the smaller maps, but I dont know how I would do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I use for k, v := range channel it tells me to many variables in range

That's because a channel is only a list of values, there is no key.  So do this:

```
for val := range channel {
    // ..
}
```

Now `val` will be one of your maps, each time through the loop, so you'll probably want to range over that, too:

```
for val := range channel {
    for k, v := range val {
        // Put your aggregation logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah now I understand, thank you for your help Flimzy, will try and implement it now :)